# Is vegetarianism accepted in Islam?

Tags: halal-haram, food, behavior

Islam teaches us what is halal food and what is haram food. It is said that we should eat from the foods that Allah has made halal for us.

So, while some people become vegetarian, that is mostly because of their psychological state so far I have seen. And since they are ignoring some of the food that was made halal for them, any chance to consider it as ignorance?

Has Islam said anything about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be permissible to be vegetarianism about halal things. Although meat can be considered as a good food as well. Besides, there are some hadiths regarding eating meat. For instance it has narrated that the Prophet (SAWW) said:

> We Quraish are interested persons in meat. /      برقی، احمد بن محمد
>   بن خالد، المحاسن، محقق، مصحح، محدث، جلال الدین،‏ ج 2، ص 451، قم، دار
>   الکتب الإسلامیة، چاپ دوم، 1371ق.

Or even I found another narration from Imam Jafar al Sadiq (a.s.) as the sixth Imam of Shiite school of thought who talked concerning meat that you can see it in the reference (if you are familiar in Farsi).

Anyhow, it demonstrates meat as a positive food (by observing...).      But there is a nice significant point as a related rule, that is related to the harming. Actually there is a rule in Islam which says harming the body is counted as a haram practice. So you should pay heed that being vegetarianism cannot be accepted or permissible if it harms the body due to "not eating meat for a long time (for the things which are necessary for the body).

Answer (score 1):

It is suitable for people to be vetetarianism to eat plenty of vegetables. Because there are much vitamina in it. But it can I think just eating the vegetables is not adequate for persons as complete. Because people's bodies needs various things such as vitamins, proteins and so on. So Islam encourage humans to keep their bodies health. Therefore we should keep our bodies healthy by having adequate program of feedings.

But if we want to survey the matter from the aspect of compulsory, then there is no problem about that. In fact I mean in case you have to eat vegetables, then Islam and Allah won't torture you because of that. Because you have not choose this manner of eatings optional. But perhaps there would be problems if your behaviour damage your body.