# Eating meat compulsory?

Tags: fiqh, food, meat

Bismillah, Assalam o Alekum.

I have heard from some people that eating meat is compulsory in Islam. They mention a hadis , whose exact words I can't recall but its meaning is , that if one has not eaten meat for a particular period of days(may be weeks or months), then he must buy and eat meat , even if he has to take a debt to buy that meat. People also say that those who never eat meat disbelief.

What I recently read on an Islamic website is this that being vegetarian is totally allowed in Islam, and meat consumption is not compulsory.

I am confused over this. Is the hadis fabricated, because although I have heard it from people, I have never heard it from a scholar. Please explain this . Thank you.

Comment: Eating meat is not obligatory in Islam. If you avoid it because of personal taste then it is allowed, however doing it with the thought that being vegetarian is more moral or correct is wrong and may be classed as disbelief [5:87-88](https://quran.com/5/87-89).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is vegetarianism accepted in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/24816/is-vegetarianism-accepted-in-islam)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven’t heard about the hadith which you have mentioned, it will be better if you provide the citation (Book Names, Hadith No etc), but I will give viewpoint of many Islamic Scholars on the same issue: -

- Dr. Zakir Naik: -
  A Muslim can be a very good Muslim despite being a pure vegetarian. It is not
  compulsory for a Muslim to have non-vegetarian food.

The Qur’an, permits a Muslim to have non-vegetarian food. The
following Qur’anic verses are proof of this fact:

> “O ye who believe! Fulfil (all) obligations. Lawful unto you (for food) are all four-footed animals with the exceptions named.”
>   [Al-Qur’an 5:1](https://quran.com/5/1)
>
> “O ye people! Eat of what is on earth, lawful and good”
>   [Al-Qur’an 2:168](https://quran.com/2/168)

- Mufti Ebrahim Desai: -
  A Muslim may be a vegetarian. However, he should not regard eating meat as prohibited.
- Sayyid Fadhlullah: -
  Vegetarianism is halal. Meat is not compulsory. Any food is permissible provided it is not harmful. Muslims are free to eat whatever they want provided it is halal. It is like wanting to eat a certain fruit and not the other.
- Ayatullah Sayyid Khamanei:-
  According to Islamic law (shar`) there is no objection to it. However, eating meat is permissible in Islamic law although eating too much is reprehensible (makruh).

[Islamic Scholars viewpoints (Fatwas) on eating of meat in Islam](https://www.animalsinislam.com/halal-living/fatwas/)

[Questions answered by Dr. Zakir Naik (Islamic Scholar) regards eating of meat in Islam](https://zakirnaikqa.wordpress.com/tag/why-do-muslims-eat-non-veg-food/)