# What is the authenticity of the hadith "do not make your stomach a graveyard of animals"?

Tags: hadith, source-identification, food, authenticity, meat

In [my answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/47122/17163) to [How often should we eat meat?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/47109/17163), I quote two ahadith which I'm unsure about their reliability.  The first is

> Hazrat Ali Ibn Abi Talib, the cousin and son-in-law of Prophet Muhammad, the fourth Khalifa as per Sunni belief, has been quoted in Sharh Nahjul Balagha, as saying: “Do not make your stomach a graveyard of animals”.
>   <sub>[dailypioneer.com](http://www.dailypioneer.com/columnists/oped/eating-beef-not-an-islamic-ritual.html)</sub>

A variant of this hadith is found on what seems to be a Hare Krishna website:

> Once the Holy Prophet Muhammad orders Hazrat Ali: “Don’t make your stomach a grave yard of innocent birds and animals.” From that day Hazrat Ali had faithfully followed this instruction.
>   <sub>[harekrsna.de](http://www.harekrsna.de/artikel/islam-vegetarianism.htm)</sub>

I didn't find a reliable source for this hadith, nor was I able to determine its level of authenticity.

**Question**: What is the authenticity of this hadith?

(I asked about the other hadith here: [What is the authenticity of the hadith "if you eat meat for 40 days, those qualities will come within you"?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/47145/17163))

Comment: Please add "(pbuh)" or "(saw)" after our Prophet Mohammed (saw) .

Comment: The relevant meta posts are: [1](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/36/17163), [2](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/17163), [3](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1131/17163).  This topic is not relevant to the question.

Comment: Still I'm not convinced. I do think that you need to do it just so you show your gratitude among the Prophet.

Comment: I so far only found it quoted as a statement of 'Ali in a commentary of nahj al-Balagha. Which would mean it is hard to qualify the authenticity.

Comment: @AnonymousI you are free to add it in your mind, but this discussion IMO is closed on islam SE.

Answer (score 3):

The hadith that you quoted is not in any Sunni book that I have come across. Some have attributed this saying to [Abū al-'Alā' al-Ma'arri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Ma%CA%BFarri) but without citing references. An unattributed saying (potentially words of wisdom preserved through tradition over time) was documented by [Muhammad al-Munawi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_al-Munawi) in *Fayd al-Qadīr*:

> وكبعض الحكماء حيث قال: يا أبناء الحكمة لا تجعلوا بطونكم قبورا للحيوان
>
> <sub>— **NOTE**: My own translation, so treat with care.</sub>
>
> And as some wise men say: "O sons of wisdom, do not turn your stomachs into graveyards for animals."
>
> <sub>— [Fayd al-Qadīr Sharh al-Jami' as-Saghīr 2/52](https://al-maktaba.org/book/21660/1315#p1)</sub>

In *Fasl al-Khitāb* [2/526](https://al-maktaba.org/book/32027/527#p1), Mohammad Nasr ad-Dīn Mohammad 'Uwaida attributed it to ['Ali ibn Abi Tālib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ali), with almost identical wording, but again without citing a chain of narration or any other references.